# Unable to increase Virtual Machine Size through Azure Management Portal

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, iaas

I am trying to change the Virtual machine size from - 8 Cores, 14 GB to A 6 - 4 core, 28 GB for one of of my MSSQL Azure IaaS server.

I am getting the following error:

> Unable to upgrade the deployment. The requested VM size may not be
>   available in the resources supporting the existing deployment. Please
>   try again later, try with a smaller VM size or smaller number of role
>   instances, or create a deployment under an empty hosted service with a
>   new affinity group or no affinity group binding. The long running
>   operation tracking ID was: 1d8145d1977877978d1d8dffdd045d83.

I understand that there is a limitation on how much one can get from one subscription. However, this is the live server and I have another 4 servers running under same subscription. Is there any way I can move this Virtual machine from one subscription to an another?

Otherwise, what is the right approach on increasing the size of this server?

Please advise the earliest.

Comment: I recommend you contact support.

Comment: How many cores are on your subscription and how many are currently in use?

Comment: @codingoutloud mate I have talked with the support department.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the answer from Support as :

> When customer initially deployed service it got deployed under the
>   cluster which does not support high memory VM's. Since customer is
>   having deployment under the hosted service it cannot be
>   pinned/migrated to a cluster which supports A6 or higher VM size. This
>   is a by design behaviour as of now. Unfortunately, the only way
>   customer can deploy a A6 VM is to delete and recreate deployment with
>   A6 size under the given hosted service. When customer tries to create
>   it, then he/she will be allocated a cluster which supports A6 or
>   higher VM size.